Unitarity and renormalizability in $R_\xi$ and 't Hooft gauge
Consider the massive propagator with gauge fixing $\frac{1}{2a} (\partial A)^2$
$$
\Delta_{\mu\nu}=-i\left[\frac{g_{\mu\nu}}{k^2-m^2}-\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{m^2}\left(\frac{1}{k^2-m^2}-\frac{1}{k^2-am^2}\right)\right].
$$
In $a\to 0$ limit, it will have the following form
$$
\Delta_{\mu\nu}=-\frac{g_{\mu\nu}-\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{k^2}}{k^2-m^2}.
$$
This is said to be renormalizable, but not unitary. It is renormalizable is easy to see from the power counting but how this is not unitary? One way to check is to see the diagonal components. Similarly, at the limit $a\to \infty$, the propagator becomes
$$
\Delta_{\mu\nu}=-\frac{g_{\mu\nu}-\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{m^2}}{k^2-m^2}.
$$
This is said to be not renormalizable, but unitary. This is not renormalizable because at $k\to \infty$, this becomes constant. But what about the unitarity?
The rephrased question can be asked, for $a\to 0$, we expect the zeroth component $\Delta_{00}$ not to vanish, but for $a\to \infty$, this should vanish. But it does not seem so.

Said where? Which page? How is the mass compatible with gauge symmetry? Via the Stueckelberg mechanism? Via the Higgs mechanism? Also note that $a\equiv\xi$.

this should be quite familiar statement, so I have not given any reference. For more, see Branco, Lavoura, Silva chapter 11, Page 149. Yes Stuckelberg mechanism

Why are you gauge-fixing a massive vector field?

the main context is EW interactions, before spontaneous symmetry breaking, so the massive gauge bosons are still not there
